# Is $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$ separable or linear?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider differential equation $y'-1=e^{x^2}y$. I ask two questions, is it separable, and is it linear. First of all I think is separable, because there's $e^{x^2}$ and $y$, so it's separate by dividing. Second of all is it linear differential equation. For this, I think is not linear, because it's $e^{x^2}$ for coefficient..

Comment: Separable: Do you can write the diff. equation as $N\left( y \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = M\left( x \right)$? Linear: A linear diff. equation has the form $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} + p\left( x \right)y = g\left( x \right)$

Comment: Linear and not separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be written as
$$y'=1+\mathrm{e}^{x^2}y =:f(x,y). $$
Suppose $f(x,y)=M(x)N(y)$ is separable. $f$ then satisfies the PDE

$$f f_{xy} = f_x f_y (=M N M' N'). $$

However, we get

$$f f_{xy}-f_x f_y=2 xe^{x^2} \not\equiv 0.$$

This proves the equation is **not** separable.

It is linear, however.